# Configure python hanging indent after an open parenthesis

Tags: emacs, indentation

Emacs indents my code like this:

```
def my_function(
    a, b, c):
    pass

if my_function(
    1, 2, 3):
    pass
```

However, PEP8 states that it should be indented like this, to avoid confusing the hanging indent with the next line:

```
def my_function(
        a, b, c):
    pass

if my_function(
        1, 2, 3):
    pass
```

How can I configure emacs' old `python.el` to use the existing `python-continuation-offset` variable in this case (after an opening parenthesis and newline), so as to indent the second way?

Comment: I'm not sure that the `python` tag fits with this, I think it's more of an emacs-specific indentation question because this could be independent of language, right?

Comment: @spikespaz For the most part, each emacs mode has its own indentation and formatting implementation, so I think the answer would probably be specific to python-mode.  I agree though that the `python` tag probably isn't right since being a Python expert doesn't mean you're more likely to be able to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for information, Python mode in GNU Emacs 25 formats this correctly.